# Redirect using Vue Router in Nuxt JS vuex

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm building a login/register system as part of an app. I'm using Firebase and Vuex to handle authentication and database information. I have some actions in Nuxt JS that create the user, sign them in and log them out.

I'm trying to implement a redirect after the user has been successfully registered / when they click login, my code is:

```
export const actions = {

  /*
   * Create a user
   */
  createUser ({commit}, payload) {
    this.$fireAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password).then(function(firebaseUser) {
      commit('setUser', payload)
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log('error logging in' + error)
    });
  },

  /*
   * Log a user into Beacon
   */
  login ({commit}, payload) {
    this.$fireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password).then(function(firebaseUser) {
      commit('setUser', payload)
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log('error logging in' + error)
    });
  },

  /*
   * Sign a user out of Beacon
   */
  signOut ({commit}) {
    this.$fireAuth.signOut().then(() => {
      commit('setUser', null)
    }).catch(err => console.log(error))
  }

}
```

I'm using Nuxt JS 2.9.2, on Vue JS 2.6.10

I have a few modules.

I've tried using `this.router.push('/')` and `window.location.href`, but would like to retain the SPA functionality.

Comment: What's wrong with `this.$router.push` or `this.$router.replace`?

Comment: What's the problem you're having? You don't really ask any questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two ways to do it:

1. `$nuxt.$router.push` in actions
2. Pass `this.$router.push` as argument in your action, and call where you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just want to add that if you use an external function (like outside of mutations/actions) but still in the same Vuex file, you need to pass it the `router` from within the mutation/action, like `externalFunction(this.app.router)` otherwise, you could not reach it properly.

Comment: we can access `$nuxt.$router.push` in `actions`?